# TCP: Socket send/recv order

Tags: c, sockets

I am wondering if you need to set up the server and client sockets so that they always go

```
send recv send recv ...
```

Because I am getting an issue where I send a message, and then the initial send() receives it twice.

I send the message `upload foo.c`

Server displays: `Message received: upload foo.c`

But then the server prints the actual file contents, which should have been passed to another `recv()` socket call (since only the first socket in the while loop has it's contents printed)

```
Message received: This is some text from
the file foo.c
text hello ending
```

So I get the feeling it's "overflowing" into the next recv iteration.

Comment: protocol? TCP or UDP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you use TCP? Then you have to remember that TCP is a *streaming* protocol, without message boundaries and without any start or end (except connection established and closed).

A single `recv` call may receive less *or* more than what was sent in a single `send` call.

You need to come up with a higher-level protocol which incorporates message boundaries explicitly, for example by sending the length of the data to be received. Then you have to use loops to receive the correct amount of bytes.